# How to add barchart markers in Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i want to add barchart marker in my map. How is the script for that? i tried to find  any of them in the internet but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Leaflet-Minichart](https://github.com/rte-antares-rpackage/leaflet.minichart)

You can add the library with:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.minichart/dist/leaflet.minichart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

var barChartMarker = L.minichart(map.getCenter(), {data: [1,2,3]}).addTo(map)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/L8s1j6nw/